# Timeout Exception while web scraping an element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, timeoutexception

I am facing a timeout exception while trying to click on a drop down link - have tried all the solutions I could find on various forums (eg: Increasing the wait time to upto 60 sec, using time.sleep, changing locators)
but the error doesn't seem to go away.

FWIW: The page and the link I am trying to click otherwise loads in just 1 second so not sure what's going on.

Could anyone please assist on what am I missing?

The code snippet is as follows:

```
def __init__(self, driver):  # initialize each WebElement here
    self.driver = driver
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver.instance, 10)
    self.data_dropdown = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ProjectDataTab"]')))  # Data dropdown
    self.view_all_link = wait.until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            By.LINK_TEXT, 'View All')))  # View All link
```

Error stack trace:

```
ERROR: test_form_case_exports (__main__.TestCCHQ)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DSI/PycharmProjects/CCHQ_Smoke/testcases/CCHQ_1.py", line 27, in test_form_case_exports
    form_case_exports = FormCaseExports(self.driver)
  File "C:\Users\DSI\PycharmProjects\CCHQ_Smoke\pageobjects\form_case_exports.py", line 21, in __init__
    By.LINK_TEXT, 'View All')))  # View All link
  File "C:\Users\DSI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Can you add the link from where you are trying to extract the data?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up question, Vin! I guess the exception was raised because I was initializing the locator of 'View All' link in the init method, when the link appears after clicking on the 'Data' dropdown. I resolved it by moving the initialization part out of the init method. :)